# Programmatically add footnote in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to add a footnote in word with a Word-JS Add-On. Unfortunately, I found out that the office.js API is not supporting this feature.

I found a way to do it with VBA [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/word.footnotes.add), but I found no option to run VBA code from office.js

The last thing I found is some VB and C# code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.documentbase.footnotes?view=vsto-2017), but I have no Idea how to run it.

```
Private Sub DocumentFootnotes()
    Dim text As Object = "Sample footnote text."
    Me.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
    Me.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "This is sample paragraph text."
    Me.Footnotes.Location = Word.WdFootnoteLocation.wdBeneathText
    Me.Footnotes.NumberStyle = Word.WdNoteNumberStyle.wdNoteNumberStyleLowercaseRoman
    Me.Footnotes.Add(Me.Paragraphs(1).Range.Words(2).Characters(2), , text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA API is not supported to run in Office.js. The [.NET API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.documentbase.footnotes?view=vsto-2017) you've found are used in VSTO add-in. Here is a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-word?view=vs-2019) to create VSTO add-in.